# Python - Issue using list pop() method in loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

The following code:

```
list = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']

for item in list:
    removed_item = list.pop()
    print(removed_item + ' has been removed from the list')

print(list)
```

Gives the result:

```
F has been removed from the list
E has been removed from the list
D has been removed from the list
['A', 'B', 'C']
```

When I was expecting it to loop through the whole list and return and empty list. Why is it stopping half way through the list and leaving the A, B and C values in the list?

Comment: You are shortening the list while looping through it.

Comment: its usually not a good idea to modify the thing you are iterating on. Your loop starts at the beginning of the list, `pop` removes from the end of the list, and they meet in the middle.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [strange result when removing item from a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260089/strange-result-when-removing-item-from-a-list)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are removing items from the end of your list while looping through it, so you will stop after 3 iterations.  Instead, use a while loop here:

Also, **do not** name lists `list`, since you are reassigning the builtin `list` in python.

```
l = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']

while l:
    removed_item = l.pop()
    print(removed_item + ' has been removed from the list')

print(l)
```

Output:

```
F has been removed from the list
E has been removed from the list
D has been removed from the list
C has been removed from the list
B has been removed from the list
A has been removed from the list
[]
```

Here is a better explanation on why your previous method did not work:

You are looping through the list sequentially, so you will access `A, B, C, D, E, F` in that order, however, you are removing from the back of the list, so when you reach `C`, you are at the end of the list, since you have removed `D, E, and F` and the loop stops.  Your method would work if you did the following:

```
for item in reversed(l):
    removed_item = l.pop()
    print(removed_item + ' has been removed from the list')
```

Since you would be looping from the end of the list, while removing from the end of the list.

Comment: Still not clear on why exactly shortening the list would cause it to stop after 3 iterations when I have 6 items in the list.

Comment: @TommyFountain added a better explanation

Comment: @TommyFountain Because the list iterator stops and raises StopIteration when the internal incremented index matches or exceeds the *current* length of the source.  IE, when source[i] would raise IndexError.  The source list is neither copied or frozen.